# Deploy to Windows Store two different builds (x64 and x86)

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, x86, 64-bit, windows-store

i have a windows 8.1 application with two differente builds due to a video library (x86 and x64).

How can i publish both of them as the same APP in the store?
Anybody as any insight's about this?

Building as Neutral does not work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Part of the process of creating the packages for your app allows you to select the specific architectures that you want to build. In Visual Studio, right click on your project and select *Store* --> *Create App Packages*. These selections are on the very first dialog:

[image: Select Architectures Checkboxes]

As shown above, you would select both *x86* and *x64* for the *Architecture* checkboxes.  For *Solution Configuration* select *Release (x86)* and *Release (x64)*.